# Get the target MAPI Folder and EntryID of a MailItem after applying Outlook rules

Tags: c#, outlook-2007

I'm creating an Add-In for Outlook 2007, which handles `NewMailEx` event and gives the `StoreID` of the `MAPI` Folder and `EntryID` of the incoming email in that folder, after all the Outlook rules are applied to it. The Add-In will track the email later, using the `GetItemFromId()` method of `System.NameSpace class`. I tried searching with the unique `PR_SEARCH_KEY` of the mailitem, but it was taking too much time unnecessarily scanning all the folders and sub-folders. I need a way to remember an email, and not searching it again.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar; I need to find the containing folder of an Outlook contact

Answer (score 0):

When handling NewMailEx you get EntryIDCollection containing a comma separated string. These look like GUIDS. You need to save that string somewhere (or just the ID you wish to save) and then you can get the item(s) using

```
Outlook.MailItem mi = thisAddIn.Application.Session.GetItemFromID(id, Type.Missing) as Outlook.MailItem
```

Where ID is the single ID for the item you want. You'll have to call this once for each item in your collection. It doesn't matter where it ends up after the rules are applied. the ID will always be the same.

@rotard To get the contact folder just use

```
public string GetFolderFullName(Outlook.ContactItem ci) 
{
     Outlook.MAPIFolder mf = ci.Parent;
     string path = mf.FolderPath;
     return path;
 }
```